# Strange behavior when using Angular UI tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SbA9WWFGlGuQv2JI3NAy?p=preview) the user should be able to click on one of three links. Each link has a related `div` that is shown when the user clicks on the link. Also, when the link is clicked its color turns red.

Problem is that one of the links (labeled `Show 10`) doesn't work, the div is not displayed and the text is not turned red.

Note that the fields in the plunk are wrapped by an Angular UI tab. If the tab is removed ([see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HfQT8bQSXCamIjlK9mbP?p=preview)) then the problem disappears. How to fix this?

HTML (version with tabs)

```
<div ng-controller="ctl">

      <uib-tabset style="height:500px">
          <uib-tab>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                     ng-style="{'color': showItem == 0 ? 'red' : 'blue' }" 
                     ng-click="showItem=0" >Show 0</a>
                     <br>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                     ng-style="{'color': showItem == 10 ? 'red' : 'blue' }" 
                     ng-click="displaySeries()">Show 10</a>
                     <br>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                    ng-style="{'color': showItem == 20  ? 'red' : 'blue' }"
                    ng-click="showItem=20" >Show 20</a>
             <div ng-show="showItem==0">
                   zero
             </div>
            <div ng-show="showItem==10">
                   ten
             </div>
             <div ng-show="showItem==20">
                   twenty
             </div>
           </uib-tab>
       </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

Javascript (version with tabs)

```
var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.showItem = 10;

      $scope.displaySeries = function(){
            $scope.showItem = 10;
      };    

});
```

Comment: Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/hwMVdtitZ8x1CbNgBsZ6?p=preview

Comment: works perfectly, why didn't you answer the question?

Comment: Because i'm too lazy to write a complete description in my answer :( But basically you should use dot notation (i.e - Object) when using tabs

Answer (score 0):

in that `a` tag, you missed to input `ng-click="showItem=10"`  (currently you have `ng-click="displaySeries()"`)

Comment: ng-click="displaySeries()" is fine, the method is setting the value of showItem. Also, note that it's the same code with and without the tabs - and without the tabs works fine.

Comment: I've updated answer,I had error. Now, see answer again, it solves.

Comment: see my previous comment